# Install macOS ARM in VMWare Fusion on an M3 Mac

Tags: macos, vmware

I'm trying to install a macos arm64 VM, but there's no such option on VMWare Fusion now,

[image]

On Intel Mac I can install the VM from recovery partition. Is there a way to do that on MacOS?

Comment: Apple has made lightweight macOS VMs *simple.* There are a number of shareware apps that allow this including here https://eclecticlight.co/downloads/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the document [Using VMware Fusion](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/13/fusion-13-user-guide.pdf) basically states Apple Silicon Macs need to be running VMware Fusion 13.0.0 and later, the document does not do a good job explaining which guest operating systems are supported. I found this [VMware Compatibility Guide](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=software&details=1&osBits=arm(64-bit)&page=1&display_interval=10&sortColumn=Partner&sortOrder=Asc&testConfig=16), where I selected `arm(64-bit)` for “OS Arch”. Here is a snapshot of the results.

[image]

Based on the results, no ARM based versions of macOS can be guests on any VMware products.

---

### Alternatives:

Parallels has published the article [Install macOS virtual machine on a Mac with Apple silicon](https://kb.parallels.com/125561/), which confirms their product can run macOS virtual machines on a Macs with Apple silicon. The top part of this article is shown below.

[image]

Comment: Does this mean VMWare can't make macOS VMs on M-series? That's pretty weak. So you'd have to use a different VM host app, like Parallels or UTM.

Comment: @benwiggy: I updated my answer to state Parallels should be able make macOS VMs on M-series. So, this is possible. I assume VMware just has not caught up yet.

Answer (score 1):

VMware does not support macOS guests on ARM currently.

Parallels does.

Comment: As does Eclectic Light Company's Viable. See Steve Chambers comment on the question.