# How to install macOS Ventura on an M3 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, apple-silicon, ventura

I just bought a new M3 MacBook Pro 16". It has macOS Sonoma 14.3.1 (after upgrading from the pre-installed version - 14.3 I think).

I am an app developer and I wish to support macOS 12+ for one of my apps. So my goal is to install macOS 12 and macOS 13, along with macOS 14, in separate partitions on the new Mac so I can occasionally test my app on the older OS versions.

According to Apple's support page [macOS Ventura is compatible with these computers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102861), Ventura is compatible with "MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2023)".

According to Apple's support page [How to download and install macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102662), I can download the Ventura installer from the macOS App Store app. The "Get" button will be enabled if compatible. Sure enough, when I view Ventura in the App Store app I see the "Get" button and it is enabled. Clicking on the "Get" button takes me to the Settings app's Software Update screen. After a moment of "Checking for updates...", I get a dialog that states:

> Update not found. The requested version of macOS is not available. Please check if your Mac is compatible with this software.

Can Ventura be installed on an M3 MacBook Pro or not? If so, how can I get around the problem of downloading the installer?

I also looked within the developer.apple.com/downloads website and couldn't find a link to Ventura.

I still have my old 2018 Intel MacBook Pro 15" running macOS 14.3. Following the same steps, I am able to download macOS Ventura on that Mac. But before I download a 12GB file on that computer, I want to know if it would even work on the new M3 MacBook Pro.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151439/discussion-on-question-by-hangarrash-how-to-install-macos-ventura-on-an-m3-macbo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

According to [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/by_year/macs-released-in-2023.html), the earliest version of macOS which is compatible with your Mac is macOS 14.1 (23B2073). I assume here that this is the first build which included the drivers to support your Mac's hardware.

When using Xcode to build an application, you would have to select backward compatibility with macOS 12+. This should make actual testing on Monterey and Ventura unnecessary. You could use an older Mac which is compatible with Monterey and Ventura to test, but you would be only testing the software on that older model Mac and not all Macs capable of running Monterey and Ventura. Furthermore, the testing would be either on an Intel or Apple Silicon.

You could purchase Parallels to run Monterey and Ventura in a virtual machine on your current 2023 M3 MacBook Pro. From my understanding [VMware Fusion Player](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/468948/install-macos-arm-in-vmware-fusion-on-an-m3-mac) and VirtualBox cannot host Monterey and Ventura on Apple Silicon Macs. Some other possible virtual machine software is listed in this [The Eclectic Light Company](https://eclecticlight.co/downloads/) article.

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify where the everymac.com page indicates the earliest compatible version of macOS? The only reference to macOS 14.1 I see on the page for my Mac is the entry for the pre-installed macOS version. There's an entry for maximum macOS but no entry that I see for minimum macOS version.

Comment: FYI - Actual testing on Monterey and Ventura is quite necessary. There's always differences and bugs across OS versions. My app has been supporting macOS 12 for the last year and there have been a few issues between OS versions. Moving to Sonoma resulted in a few more. Anyway, I'm now looking into using UTM to virtualize Monterey and Ventura.

Comment: HangarRash: There are three different Macs in the [list](https://everymac.com/systems/by_year/macs-released-in-2023.html) at everymac.com match your description of **M3 MacBook Pro 16"**. By selecting any one of the three, then looking for **Pre-Installed MacOS:**, you will find **macOS 14.1 (23B2073)**. For example, by selecting **MacBook Pro "M3 Pro" 12 CPU/18 GPU 16"**, you would be taken to [here](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-m3-pro-12-core-cpu-18-core-gpu-16-late-2023-specs.html).

Comment: I get that. But what I don't see is a "minimum macOS" entry. I see the "pre-installed" entry, I see the "maximum macOS" entry. But there's no "minimum macOS" entry. Your answer seems to imply that "pre-installed" means the "minimum". Is that correct?

Comment: Well, this has come up before here a Ask Different. Others may disagree with what I am about to post. My experience has been that Pre-Installed MacOS means you cannot install anything earlier. Others have posted that under certain circumstances the minimum may be newer than what everymac.com posts as the Pre-Installed MacOS.