# How to develop and test a macOS app that supports multiple versions of macOS using one MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, xcode, virtualization, dual-boot, testflight

I am an iOS/macOS app developer. I have an app that supports macOS 12/13/14. I have a new (November 2023) M3 MacBook Pro running macOS 14.3.1.

I have a need to also run macOS 12 and macOS 13 on this same MacBook Pro so I can test the app to ensure all functionality works correctly on all supported versions of macOS.

I originally intended to install macOS 12 and 13 in their own partitions and use dual (triple) boot as needed. However, this failed because the new Mac doesn't support anything older than macOS 14.1. See [How to install macOS Ventura on an M3 MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/469154/how-to-install-macos-ventura-on-an-m3-macbook-pro?noredirect=1#comment697872_469154) for a related post I made about trying to get macOS Ventura installed on the new Mac. Post an answer there if you know of a solution for that. Such a solution would render most of this post moot.

Then I moved to virtualization. I downloaded and setup [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app). I had no issue installing macOS 13.6 after downloading the appropriate ipsw file from Apple. But then the roadblock showed up. It turns out that macOS running in a virtual machine on an Apple Silicon host does not support the ability to log into an AppleID. See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707682 for tons of comments on this. The post by Apple employee "Eskimo" near the top of the thread has the most relevant info:

> - Apple silicon macOS virtual machine don’t support Apple ID logins.
> - This has been true since the Virtualization framework was introduced in macOS 11.
> - It’s still true in macOS 14 (currently in beta).
> - This means that a number of important workflows don’t work in such VMs.
> - Apple has made no official announcement about whether this will change in the future.

This restriction causes the following pain points trying to do app development and testing:

- You can't download any software via the App Store app since you can't log into the store. This is easy enough to work around by downloading on the host and copying to the guest VM.
- You can't download any TestFlight test apps since you can't log into TestFlight.
- You can't test any iCloud functionality in the app since you can't log into iCloud.

I've attempted to work around some of these issues.

- Running Xcode on the host, I built a development build of the app. I then copied the resulting app to a shared folder available to the guest VM. When I then attempt to run that version of the app from the guest VM, I get a dialog popup that states that "The application XXX can't be opened".
- I submitted a build and made it available via TestFlight. I downloaded the app via TestFlight on the host. I then copied the resulting app to a shared folder available to the guest VM. When I then attempt to run that version of the app from the guest VM, I get a dialog popup that states that the app is no longer available due to the provisioning profile being invalid.

So I can't run a development build and I can't run a TestFlight build. I did verify that I can download the app from the App Store on the host, copy that to the VM, and then successfully run it from the guest VM. It's only the development and TestFlight builds that fail.

If I could run TestFlight in the guest VM then I'm sure that would work. But since you can't log into the AppleID in the guest VM, that's not an option.

**How do I build my app on my host Mac in such a way that I can run it in one or more guest VMs?***

Comment: Help me improve the question. Why the downvote? The question shows lots of research effort. I think it is clear enough. And wouldn't this be useful to any developer trying to test an app on multiple versions of macOS?

Answer (score 1):

I found a partial solution that will allow a development build done on the host Mac to run in a guest VM. It turns out that the problem is related to the provisioning profile and its registered devices.

My Xcode project is setup to do automatic signing. It's so much simpler than doing it manually. However, the downside of automatic provisioning is that the generated provisioning profile is only valid for the device you perform the build on.

The solution is to turn off the "Automatically manage signing" option. You then need to setup an appropriate provisioning profile that includes all of the macOS (real and virtual) devices that you wish to run the app on.

For each macOS instance, run the System Settings app (macOS 13 & 14). Go to General -> About. Scroll down and click on "System Report". In the generated report look for the value "Provisioning UDID". You will need that value for each host/VM. Under macOS 12, click the Apple icon in the top-left and select "About this Mac". Then click on "System Report" in the dialog.

Note: The following links (except for "Apple Developer") require that you be a registered Apple Developer

Go to the [Account](https://developer.apple.com/account) page of the [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com) site and click on [Devices](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/list).

Add a new device for each VM (and host Mac if not already there). Choose macOS for the platform. Give it a name. Enter the "Provisioning UDID" from the System Report into the "Device ID (UUID)" field.

Once all of the devices are setup, go to the [Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list) page and create a provisioning profile with the appropriate certificate and bundle id. Select all of the macOS devices you need. Once created, download it to your host Mac.

In your Xcode project you need to import that downloaded profile into the Provisioning Profile entry for your macOS app.

Once in place you can build the app normally. Copy the built app to a VM and it should now run. Or do an Archive build and click on Distribute App. Choose Debugging or Custom and complete the export. Copy the exported app to the VM. The Custom option takes more steps but gives you more options than selecting Debugging.

While this lets you build the app in Xcode on the host Mac and run it in a VM, it still requires a lot of extra work. You have to update the device and provisioning profile anytime you create a new VM. It's extra steps to copy the built app to the VM. There's also no way to test any iCloud features (such as CloudKit) or any other features that require the user to be logged into an AppleID.

Comment: All your links are not accessible. For example, I get this [popup](https://i.imgur.com/bagI0FB.png). You might consider replacing each link with a snapshot.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yes, you need to be a registered (and probably signed in) Apple developer to get to the all of the links except for the main "Apple Developer" link. The info is useless to anyone that can't sign in as a developer. I added a note to the answer.